# What are the default shortcuts for "Align Center" and "Align Middle"?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

From other programs, I'm used to something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>M</kbd> or similar.

[image: screenshot]

Edit: Apparently it is also not possible to define custom shortcuts in PowerPoint? Please correct me if this is wrong/outdated info.

Comment: This is very easy to find using a search engine. What have you tried?

Comment: That's correct; you cannot define custom shortcuts in PowerPoint, though there are third-party add-ins that help with this. OfficeOne's Shortcut Manager is one such. http://www.officeoneonline.com/

Answer (score 5):

Add the required align option to the quick access tool bar. Reorder these items if necessary so that the align options are in are say 3 and 4. Then alt-3 or alt-4 will select them with a single key stroke.  (Using ppt 2016)

This also works for 2013 and 2010, by the way.

Here's a short video that explains how to customize the Quick Access Toolbar (QAT to its friends) 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-the-Quick-Access-Toolbar-43fff1c9-ebc4-4963-bdbd-c2b6b0739e52

Comment: Who is Jake, and how does that part of your answer help to understand this answer here?

Answer (score 3):

The closest to a default shortcut I could find so far is the ribbon keyboard navigation:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>C/M</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Jake for your edit, but I think this style is normally used for shortcuts where all keys are pressed simultaneously. In this case they are pressed sequentually.

Answer (score 0):

#### What are the default shortcuts for “Align Center” and “Align Middle”?

There are no default shortcuts for these operations.

However, there is a (paid) add-on [PowerPoint ShortcutTools 3.0](http://www.shortcuttools.com/en/buy.html) that adds these and many other shortcuts.

Here are just some of the new shortcuts. Note they have different names for the functionality.

[image]

Source [All PowerPoint Shortcut Tools Commands](http://www.shortcuttools.com/en/powerpoint_shortcuts.html#allshortcuts)